R shinyFiles: How to select a directory in Windows system
I want to select a directory using R package shinyFiles. It works in my MAC system, but it does not work in my windows system.
For instance, i want to find a folder in Disk D, but I could not see it.
Here is my demo:
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  shinyDirButton(id = 'folder', label = 'Folder select', title = 'Select a folder'),
  verbatimTextOutput('filepaths')
))
server <- function(input, output){
  shinyFiles::shinyDirChoose(input, id = "folder", roots = c(wd = "/", home = "~"))
  output$filepaths <- renderPrint(input$folder)
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)


To get the volumes (disks) available on your system, you have to use the getVolumes function. This function returns a function, and you have to do getVolumes()() to get a named vector of the available volumes:
library(shinyFiles)
getVolumes()()

On my system, I get:
Windows (C:)         (Q:)         (Y:)         (Z:) 
       "C:/"        "Q:/"        "Y:/"        "Z:/" 

So you have to do as follows in your app:
shinyDirChoose(input, id = "folder", roots = c(getVolumes()(), wd = "/", home = "~"))

